# Why is preventDefault() not working?

Tags: javascript

I have been trying to get it to work with no luck so far. If I use return false; it works but not with prevenDefault, is there something that I'm missing? Thank you.

```
<html>
<meta http-equiv = "Content-Type" content = "text/html; charset = utf-8">
<script>
function hit(e) {
e.preventDefault();

}
</script>

<body>
<form onsubmit="hit()">
  <input type="submit" value="submit" />
</form>
<div id="d"> </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: how do you think `<form onsubmit="hit()">` works? At what point do you provide an event to `hit`?

Comment: With the code shown I wouldn't expect `return false` within the hit() function to work either.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/2jdqLvga/ You need to pass the event object. Note the console output.

Answer (score 2):

The event object is the first argument of the event handler function, which is `onsubmit`. `hit` is a function you are calling from `onsubmit` and you aren't passing it any arguments.

Bind your event handler with JavaScript, not HTML.

```
addEventListener("load", bind_event_handlers);
function bind_event_handlers(e) {
    document.querySelector("form").addEventListener("submit", hit);
    function hit(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
    }
}
```

Comment: You have written `addEventListener` alone to make the event to be bound automatically to window. Right? Just for a clarification.

Comment: @RajaprabhuAravindasamy — Yes. That's where the document's `load` event fires.

Answer (score 2):

You have to pass the `event` object explicitly in the inline event handler,

```
<form onsubmit="hit(event)">
```

But it is advised to use dedicated event handler for this type of tasks like,

```
document.querySelector("form").addEventListener("submit",function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
},false)
```

Comment: Aah, I was missing the event object, although I tried this too, I used 'e' instead of 'event'. Thanks you just stopped me from jumping over the bridge.

Comment: @user3311392 Glad to help! :)

Answer (score 1):

You can also use return inside the `onsubmit` to prevent submitting the form:

```
<script>
function hit() {
return false; // Use 'true' to submit the form

}
</script>

<body>
<form onsubmit="return hit();">
  <input type="submit" value="submit" />
</form>
<div id="d"> </div>
```

Comment: I actually did this successfully before posting the question, I just wanted to know how to use preventDefault(). Thanks.

Comment: Sure! So @Quentin and Rajaprabhu Aravindasamy answers are correct in that case. Good luck!

Answer (score -5):

Change the `onsubmit` to `onsubmit="hit"`

Comment: Did you test this?